# mongo unwind nested array of objects to get get object ids by availiable field

Tags: mongodb

I have a collections like this:

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("4d663451d1e7242c4b68e000"), 
  "topic" : "abc", 
  "available": true,
  "subLevels" : [
      {
          "id" : 1,
          "available":false
      },
      {
          "id" : 2,
          "available":true
      }
   ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d6634514cb5cb2c4b69e000"), 
    "topic" : "bce", 
    "available": true,
    "subLevels" : [
         {
             "id" : 1,
             "available":false
         },
         {
              "id" : 2,
              "available":false
         },
         {
              "id" : 3,
              "available":true
         },
      ]
}
```

And I need to get list of available sublevel id's ,in this case it should be 2 and 3

I found that is should be done some how with a aggregation `$unwind` function,but it's not working for me..

I tried it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
        "subLevels.available": true
    }},
  { $unwind : {
       path: "$subLevels",
        includeArrayIndex: "availableSublevels"
      }
  },
 {$group : {"_id" : '$availableSublevels.id'}}
])
```

but result is a single row `{"id" : null}`, how can I do this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
      //only take the ones that have at least one available as true
    $match: {
      "subLevels.available": true,
    },
  },
  {
      //unwind the array
    $unwind: {
      path: "$subLevels",
    },
  },
  {
      //filter out unavailable ones
    $match: {
      "subLevels.available": true,
    },
  },
  {
      //project out only ids
    $project: {
      "subLevels.id": 1,
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: it's working! what if I need remove duplicates?? Can I add ` {$group : {"_id" : '$subLevels.id'}}` instead of `project` ? Looks like I can but my real collection is very big and hard to test if the result correct :)

Comment: Correct. And make sure you run explain plan on it too, to make sure it is efficient. Simply speaking, you'd need an index to support your query.